# IIS 8.5 new suspend option

Tags: iis-8

I configured Windows 2012R2 with IIS 8.5 and turned on the new suspend option.

According to the documentation the state is written to disk and resources freed up.

I have a site that is strong on SignalR, when the site is started there is always a never-exiting thread that keeps track of parameters of a game, users come to the site, play the game and the state is saved in the database.

Before when the site terminated it would load everything from database to restore the game-state, which worked fine but it took a REAL long time before the site would start (sometimes up to 5 minutes).

Now I configured the suspend option and it looks to work fine, site starts up in matter of seconds, BUT the never-ending thread.. has ended.

What could be the culprit? Is there an event that is called when the site goes into suspend or comes out of suspend instead of a cold startup?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to run background threads within IIS. See http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

Possible solution is to have a Windows Service (I recommend [TopShelf](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf/) for easy bootstrap) that runs your background operations and communicates with your ASP.NET via API.

See this question: [IIS Background thread and SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942591/iis-background-thread-and-signalr)

Comment: I honestly haven't had problems for a while now. I switched servers which is more reliable and haven't had problems anymore with the suspended threads.